# How to instantiate a subtype inside a dynamic class?

Tags: c#, dynamic

I'm using C# dynamic keyword and I've got an instance where I need to set a property value.

However, this property requires a type that I have no access to since I generated an assembly in memory from WSDL.

How can I create the property instance dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a property instance; there is:

- an instance of an object
- which has members (which may be dynamic in this case)
- to which you want to assign a value

If you don't know the type of the value in advance, you will need to create the object with a combination of reflection (from the Type) and perhaps dynamic. The latter depends on whether the underlying object is *actually* dynamic, vs being a regular type exposed via the dynamic API. Likewise, whether you can assign the value to the property via reflection - or whether you ***must*** use the dynamic API - depends on the same. Fortunately, there are tools like FastMember which allow you to access arbitrary members (with names known only at runtime, not compile-time) identically for the two cases. So if the scenario is complex, maybe give that a whirl.

Comment: Yeah, bad phrasing on my part. I meant an instance of the type exposed by the property. Thanks for the tip on FastMember, I'll check it out. I've also seen Fasterflect and reading on it now.